# Django: Should I have complex template variable names or complex views

Tags: django

In django, which should I generally prefer, and why?

- long template variable names, passing as few "root objects" (e.g. request) as possible:

  `{% if request.current_page.get_children.0.get_absolute_url %}`
- or pass a hell lot of different "root objects" and keep the template variable name simple:

  `{% if first_child_url %}`
- somewhere in the middle, e.g. passing `children`

  `{% if children.0.get_absolute_url %}`

  or passing `first_child`

  `{% if first_child.get_absolute_url %}`

the advantage of the first approach is looser coupling, since I won't need to change the view every time I need to use another variable; the advantage of the second approach is that the template is simpler and much cleaner.

If I'm using generic views (or third party views) which does not allow me to add additional context variables (therefore the only way to add context variables is by writing middleware or context processors), would that change anything?

Comment: You can add extra context in generic views (at least in Django 1.3). Check it out [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/) find the variable extra_context, you can add anything there.

Comment: @Hassek: I'm using [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/), whose view does not allow me to pass extra_context, I might be missing something but I don't see any other way to pass extra context variables to django-cms pages other than middleware and context processor.

Comment: oh well that changes the rules. Haven't used django-cms at all :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right answer for this, but I can give you something else to consider:

1) Mistyped variable names in a template will fail silently, which is why I normally try to avoid things like

```
{% if request.current_page.get_children.0.get_absolute_url %}
```

2) In contrast to that, any issues in a view will immediately raise exceptions and be obvious to debug

```
first_child_url = request.current_page.get_children[0].get_absolute_url
```

3) What I sometimes do when the situation calls for it, is add shortcut methods to a model which allows me to call the method from the template but still keeping the complexity on the python side of the equation.

All that said, if you can't add extra context and need to do it using template tags (as mentioned in your comments) I think its best if you go for the complicated template option. 
I only use custom template tags when it is the only way to do something, never as a shortcut.

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 2):

If you're the only developer, it's mostly a matter of taste. However, if the one coding the views is not the one writing the templates, it's much easier to cooperate with well-defined "contracts" between view and template.

I tend to think of the view's parameters to a template the same way I think about API interfaces. My website logic can change, but as long as I respect the data structure passed to the template, I don't need to rewrite anything -- and when working in a group, this is of vital importance.